# How to limit javac output?

Tags: java, javac

Let's say I create a class that has some syntax errors and run `javac Main.java` to compile it. It shows me the following, as I would expect:

```
Main.java:3: error: '{' expected
public class Main 
                 ^
Main.java:4: error: ')' expected
    public static void main(String[] args {
                                         ^
2 errors
```

I'm looking for a way to limit that output so it only shows the error message and line number and doesn't reiterate my broken code. Something like this would be ideal:

```
Main:java:3: error: '{' expected
Main.java:4: error: ')' expected
```

I've tried a few different parameters that I found in `javac -help`, such as:

```
javac -g:lines Main.java
javac -g:none Main.java
```

But neither of these affect the output at all. Is this something I can do using command line parameters or will I just have to write some regex to filter it out? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to limit the output this way? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Progman I’m writing a wrapper for javac and will be parsing its output in another language

Comment: Best way? Fix the errors in your program, then it doesn't complain hardly at all.

Comment: @vqdave Is is possible to use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html? Java provide an API where you can access the compiler, so you don't have to run the external program "javac" to do what you could do inside your code instead.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Yeah, obviously. That's not what my question is about. If you read my comment above, I said that this was for a wrapper, so I'm not the end user of this

Comment: @Progman No because I'm invoking `javac` from the command line using PHP's functions

Comment: @vqdave Details like that belong in the question (not in a comment), regardless - rather then modify javac output, parse it (the current output) yourself (since you're doing this programmatically) - then you can output whatever you like.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch As I mentioned in my _question_, I understand that it can be done using regex and other string manipulation functions in PHP. But I'm asking specifically about javac's command line options so I can keep my wrapper script as simple as possible

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, there are no `javac` switches / options that will filter compiler error messages in the way that you want.

> I’m writing a wrapper for javac and will be parsing its output in another language

The simplest solution is to have the wrapper deal with it.  If you are implementing your wrapper as a Linux shell script, something like this:

```
    javac .... 2>&1 | grep " error: "
```

would be a good start<sup>1</sup>.  Note the `2>&1` is *necessary* because:

- javac writes compilation errors to stderr, and
- a shell pipeline redirects stdout, and not stderr.

> But I'm asking specifically about javac's command line options so I can keep my wrapper script as simple as possible.

It cannot be done that way<sup>2</sup>.  You are going to need to make your wrapper script more complicated.

---

<sup>1 - You might want something more sophisticated to avoid false matches; e.g. in case the character sequence `error:` appears in Java source code and gets quoted in a compilation error message.</sup>

<sup>2 - Not strictly true.  But I doubt that you would be willing to develop, maintain and distribute your own "tweaked" JDK with a `javac` that can output compilation errors differently.  Also, you could do this with some (complicated) custom Java code.  Use the tools APIs to call the compiler from Java code, and massage the compilation error messages before printing them to stdout or stderr.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

*Is this something I can do using command line parameters*.

Not to `javac`. The java compiler does not provide a built-in mechanism to alter the structure of its output. Other options exist, for example the [JDT Core Component](https://www.eclipse.org/jdt/core/) (from the link) *An incremental Java compiler. Implemented as an Eclipse builder, it is based on technology evolved from VisualAge for Java compiler.*

*or will I just have to write some regex to filter it out?*

Write a regular expression, implement your own compiler, adapt the openjdk or eclipse JDT Core Component (formerly eclipse compiler for java), investigate if any other compiler is better suited to your needs (IBM's perhaps), but writing a regular expression is probably the ***easiest*** approach.